# Why does ContourPlot not display anything?

Tags: plotting

Why

```
eq = {\[Gamma] == 15, \[Beta] == (
   840 (15 + \[Gamma])^2)/(225 + \[Gamma])^2}
xM = yM = 100
ContourPlot[eq, {\[Beta], 0, xM}, {\[Gamma], 0, yM}]
```

displays nothing? It should at least show the first curve.

Comment: `ContourPlot[Evaluate@eq, {\[Beta], 0, xM}, {\[Gamma], 0, yM}]`

Comment: Thanks. But it seems sometimes it works without Evaluate@. Why this ``randomness" ?

Comment: It works, if you directly insert eq  `ContourPlot[{\[Gamma] == 15, 
     \[Beta] == (840*(15 + \[Gamma])^2)/
         (225 + \[Gamma])^2}, 
   {\[Beta], 0, xM}, {\[Gamma], 0, yM}]`  Evaluate in the first example makes variables "known" to ContourPlot.